# Joining client records based on overlapping date ranges in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Client id | stayId | start_date | end_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 1-1-2010 | 20-7-2010 | A |
| 1 | 105 | 1-7-2010 | 30-12-2010 | A |
| 2 | 108. | 8-10-2012 | 10-12-2012 | B |
| 2 | 108. | 8-10-2012 | 10-12-2012 | B |

And i want to merge rows with overlapping date ranges and take the highest stayId but only if the client id and types match. How should i do this in oracle sql?

The result would look like this:

| Client id | stayId | start_date | end_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 105 | 1-1-2010 | 30-12-2010 | A |
| 2 | 108. | 8-10-2012 | 10-12-2012 | B |
| 2 | 108. | 01-01-2013 | 13-10-2013 | B |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  It looks tricky, because there can be arbitrary overlaps -- I suspect that the overlap might even be an earlier record, as in:

```
      |------|   |-------|
|------------------|
```

For this version, I recommend a cumulative max to identify the rows with no overlap.  These rows start the "islands".  Then,  a cumulative sum identifies the islands (the sum of rows where there is no overlap).  The final step is aggregation:

```
select clientid, type, max(stayid),
       min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by clientid, type
                  order by start_date
                 ) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (partition by clientid, type
                                       order by start_date
                                       range between unbounded preceding and '1' day preceding
                                      ) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by clientid, type, grp;
```